# anti-bias algorithm for rating a resturant

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, prediction, equation

i am working on a restaurant app  that user can rate a restaurant in logic for example the rating equation for 10 people is as followed:
user can rate from 1 to 5
9 had rated 5
1 had rated 1
the equation is ((9*5)+(1*1))/10(sum of people)=46/10=4.6
the answer is 4.6 which is unfair because 1 person low rate make the result to go down to 4.6 in my opinion the result should be 4.9 i searched and found something called Algorithmic bias i didn't understand it well , zomato app company found a solution for this cases like to be fair in low rating and fake ratings

so can anyone help me with a fair equation or algorithm

Comment: It's a hard problem: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612876/this-is-how-ai-bias-really-happensand-why-its-so-hard-to-fix/

Comment: It's not obvious to me why the 4.6 rating is unfair - it's pretty close to the highest possible rating of 5.

Comment: "In my opinion" - isn't that bias?

Comment: if a restaurant have 9 customers happy and one fake rating let its rating goes down to 4.6 that's not fair there is an app called zomato her in Lebanon that's had restaurant rating and in its blog its says that she had a solution for that by algorithm but its secret for that i am asking if someone can help

Comment: voting down my question will make it hard to me to ask again i am new here its just i asked for help thank you very much guys sorry for asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to square the number of people that voted for a particular rating. Compute the weighted average by multiplying each rating by the square. Then divide by the sum of the squares, and round down. That will tend to keep the rating near to the value that most people chose.

For example when the ratings are

```
5 stars from 9 people
1 star  from 1 person
```

then the calculation is

```
(5*(9*9) + 1*(1*1)) / ((9*9) + (1*1)) = 4.9
```

If you have a distribution like

```
5 stars from  4 people
4 stars from  8 people
3 start from 11 people
2 stars from  6 people
1 star  from  3 people
```

then the calculation is

```
(5*16 + 4*64 + 3*121 + 2*36 + 1*9) / (16+64+121+36+9) = 3.1
```

You can also try different formulas for weighting. For example, instead of using `n * n`, you could use `n * sqrt(n)`.

Comment: you are amazing i dont know what to say but what i can say god bless you !! thank you very much @user3386109

Comment: @AhmadBaddah Glad to help, best of luck to you!

Answer (score 3):

### Algorithmic bias

The question is far from trivial. In fact it isn't solvable at all. At least not in the mathematical way you seem to think. I'll start with an attempt to explain algorithmic bias with a few examples:

Amazon trained an AI to make hiring decisions. After some time they realized that the AI was preferring male over female applicants, due to that bias also showing up in the training dataset. In this case it's fairly trivial to decide whether the AI had an unfair bias.

Let's say I set up another AI that also decides which applicants to invite for an interview. Now I've learned from amazon and avoided the gender-bias by simply removing details like gender, name or ethnicity. No my AI can neither be racist nor sexist, so it should be fair, right? Well, my AI learned that it's better to hire applicants that are about the age of 30, simply because they have experience with state-of-the-art technology and aren't new to the industry. This would be ideal for the company (probably at least - I'll ignore that detail and just assume it for the sake of simplicity). But now we're ignoring newcomers and people who are beyond a certain age. Is this fair? It's getting a bit blurrier.

The previously described AI was dismissed as being unfair and now I've also made sure the new AI ignores age. It'll now treat newcomers the same way in which it treats someone who's 30 and someone who's more senior than that. So now it's fair, right? But now it doesn't quite care as much about experience of applicants and will give someone who has no clue the same chance as someone who has invested time and money to get experience. So is it fair? Well, I could hardly answer that question

Or last but not least: the comments to this question already show how tricky it is to define what is (un-)fair. For the rest of the question, I'll just assume that the rating-scheme you proposed is fair.

### Possible ways to modify evaluation of ratings

There are quite a few ways in which one could alternatively compile ratings. I'll only show two simple options to achieve what you want, though there certainly exist quite a few ways to mess with the numbers with a bit creativity.

[**Median**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

The median is a great statistical tool to remove skew that was caused by a few outliers among the ratings. Usually the median is calculated as the value in the middle of the sorted list - or if the number of ratings is even the average of the two middle values.

```
def median(arr):
    if len(arr) % 2 == 1:
        return sorted(arr)[len(arr) // 2]
    else:
        i = len(arr) // 2
        return sum(sorted(arr)[i - 1 : i + 1]) / 2
```

For your example with 9 5-star ratings and one 1-star rating, the result would be 5. Is it fair? Probably not, since this will treat any rating that isn't equal to the median the same way. I.e. for the above user-rating it won't make a difference whether the last user gave one star or four. On the other hand this statistic is pretty robust against skewed data with extreme outliers. So it's not the right tool here anyways.

**Combining median and arithmetic mean**

This one creates a result that is closer to what you expected - 4.8. We don't entirely ignore outliers anymore, but we've given them far less weight. So overall this rating has a strong bias towards the most common opinion, but doesn't give it quite as much value as before.

One could even add in weights for the median and average to tune how much weight is given to outliers:

```
def weighted_rating(arr, w):
    arithm = sum(arr) / len(arr)
    m = median(arr)

    return m * w + arithm * (1 - w)
```

In the above code `w` should be between 0 (arithmetic mean only) and 1 (median only). For `w = 0.75`, the rating would be 4.9. So the median has twice as much weight as the average in order to achieve such a rating.

EDIT:

A great practical approach that treats outliers in a more fair manner would be [@user3386109's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56570283/4668606). My answer was mostly meant to demonstrate the intricacies of "fair" statistics, rather than to provide any actual algorithm to calculate a rating.

Comment: +1 for recognizing the problem of the median versus the mean. In my experience, few people will argue when the median and the mean are the same. When they're different, the tendency seems to be to give more weight to the median, as suggested by your answer. However, there is a problem with the method of combining median and mean. When a distribution is strongly bimodal, the proposed method could produce a result that few people would agree is fair. For example, given 10 five-star ratings, and 9 one-star ratings, the `weighted_rating` with `w = 0.75` would be 4.5 `(5*0.75 + 3.1*0.25)`

Comment: In general, with bimodal distributions the "fair" rating tends more strongly towards the arithmetic mean than the median.

Comment: @user3386109 I just wanted to give a few simple examples on how one could achieve such an outcome. My intention with this answer was rather to show the intricacies of implementing a "fair" measure than to provide any actual measure, which your answer solved in a nice way (also +1). Anyways, I've edited my answer to make that clear.

Comment: guys you are amazing i dont know what to say but what i can say god bless you !! thank you very much @Paul

Answer (score 1):

The problem of estimating an unknown parameter (mean, variance, etc) of a randow process from a (very) low number of observations is a very difficult problem, which has been intensively studied.

The term bias is currently used here, but should not be confused with the probalistic bias (difference between the mathematical mean of the random process and the mathemetical mean of the estimation). What one wants to minimizes here is the error itself, and more precisely one wants to avoid large errors. In such situations, with a low number of voters, one simple vote can *bias* the estimation effectively.

An additional difficulty is that I am not convinced that the mean of the notations is a good criteria. An histogram of the rates (90% -> 5, 10% -> 1) is more interesting and provides more information. However, such histograms do not allow a simple sorting...

I am not a specialist of this specific problem and I only know one simple often used method: suppress the lower and higher values. However, in the proposed scenario, we get a ranking of 5, which is far to be perfect.

Another method I can think of is to perform a first rough estimation, and then to perform a new averaging with a lower weight for values too far from the first average.

However, any proposed method should be derived and checked from/with enough data: collecting a large number of votes, deriving an accurate estimation for one restaurant, and then try to obtain about the same result with any low number of votes extracted from this data base. The *best* algorithm is dependent of the probalistic law of the process, which I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is that the rating scale is subjective - and hence affected by cognitive biases of the users. Therefore the best solution would be a different rating approach, such as the Elo system - users would be asked to compare their most recently visited restaurant with the one they had visited before, thus creating a true rank-ordering of restaurants (which could allow stars to be redefined as quintiles). This article discusses the issue and possible solutions in much greater detail: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-build-truly-5-star-user-rating-tobias-baer/